# sublime text find, copy, change and paste in new line

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I need a Regex to find the certain text in document and change and paste in new line.

```
logging.info("hello i am here")
```

need to find all occurrence of logging.info and change to

```
print("hello i am here")
```

Final looks like this

```
logging.info("hello i am here")
print("hello i am here")
```

Is their any regex that i can do or i need to do manually.

Comment: Boss i need to paste it in new line not find and replace. I think you got what i mean.

Comment: Ok... now I see what you mean. The part that says `need to find all occurrence of logging.info and change to ...` threw me off. Have you tried anything yet? Is `logging.info` always alone on a line? Is there indentation that you want to keep?

Comment: yes now got me. Yes indentation is must. As i am using python code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe a regex like this should work:

```
^(\h*)logging\.info\(([^)]*)\)
```

Replace with:

```
$0\n$1print($2)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/zF0wB3)

Description:

```
^                 # Beginning of line
(\h*)             # Get any spaces/tabs before the line and store in $1
logging\.info\(   # Match 'logging.info('
([^)]*)           # Get everything between parens
\)                # Match closing paren
```

Note that the above regex assumes there are no other parens within the `logging.info` function.

The replace means:

```
$0                # Whole match
\n                # Newline
$1                # Place the indentation
print(            # 'print('
$2                # The part within the `logging.info` function
)                 # Closing paren
```

Comment: @user2190040 Did you check the regular expression mode? It's the top, leftmost button with `.*`. Here's on my ST3 version: [before](http://i.stack.imgur.com/32N8F.png) and [after](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1sHG1.png)

Comment: yes its working ^(\h*)logging\.info\(([^)]*)\) previously i was trying  ^([ ]*)logging\.info\(([^)]*)\)

Comment: @user2190040 Oh, it must have been that you were using tab characters. I initially had only spaces in the regex but only later thought about tabs. Sorry about that :(