# Regular expression to copy an an entire to next line

Tags: regex

I have been working on it from the past one hour and not able to find a solution.

I have these tag in an xml file

```
<products>  
<product>
    <product_id>1472456</product_id>
    <model>BSTWH2R</model>
    <image><![CDATA[http://www.specsserver.com/CACHE/FRGGRNGOCAFM.JPG]]></image>
    <price>100.0000</price>
    <category></category>
    <brand>Lumisource</brand>
    <title>H2 Bar Stool - Red</title>
    <productpageurl><![CDATA[http://www.appliance.com/index.php?route=product/product&modelnumber=BSTWH2R&path=1&product_id=1472456]]></productpageurl>
</product>

<product>
    <product_id>1472457</product_id>
    <model>BSTWH2W</model>
    <image><![CDATA[http://www.specsserver.com/CACHE/FREVSCQLWITW.JPG]]></image>
    <price>100.0000</price>
    <category></category>
    <brand>Lumisource</brand>
    <title>H2 Bar Stool - White</title>
    <productpageurl><![CDATA[http://www.appliance.com/index.php?route=product/product&modelnumber=BSTWH2W&path=1&product_id=1472457]]></productpageurl>
</product>
```

i want it to be changed to the below code with only the brand tag to be copied again in the next line and having one space after it

```
<products>  
<product>
    <product_id>1472456</product_id>
    <model>BSTWH2R</model>
    <image><![CDATA[http://www.specsserver.com/CACHE/FRGGRNGOCAFM.JPG]]></image>
    <price>100.0000</price>
    <category></category>
    <brand>Lumisource</brand>
    <brand>Lumisource </brand>
    <title>H2 Bar Stool - Red</title>
    <productpageurl><![CDATA[http://www.appliance.com/index.php?route=product/product&modelnumber=BSTWH2R&path=1&product_id=1472456]]></productpageurl>
</product>

<product>
    <product_id>1472457</product_id>
    <model>BSTWH2W</model>
    <image><![CDATA[http://www.specsserver.com/CACHE/FREVSCQLWITW.JPG]]></image>
    <price>100.0000</price>
    <category></category>
    <brand>Lumisource</brand>
    <brand>Lumisource </brand>
    <title>H2 Bar Stool - White</title>
    <productpageurl><![CDATA[http://www.appliance.com/index.php?route=product/product&modelnumber=BSTWH2W&path=1&product_id=1472457]]></productpageurl>
</product>
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: i tried through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557881/sublime-text-find-copy-change-and-paste-in-new-line. I tried changing it in many ways but it keeps saying invalid regular expression

Comment: If your getting an invalid regular expression. Two likley reasons. 1) Not valid in the regex you are using. What version of regex are you using(Java, php etc). 2) You are putting it in a string and didn't double backslash the backslashes.

Generally showing a short code example would really help debug this.

Comment: i am using ultraedit as a tool. It has 3 choices for regular expressions. perl, unix and ultraedit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex preserves the indentation as well as the type of the line breaks:

```
(([ \t]*<brand>[^<]*)([^\r\n]+[\r\n]+))
```

Use this as the replacement string:

```
\1\2 \3
```

See it in action [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tagkBU/3).

---

Visualization. (Click image for interactive demo):

[image: Debuggex Visualization Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

Use this Pattern `(<brand>)([^<]+)(<\/brand>)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OLyRFB/4)

```
(           # Capturing Group (1)
  <brand>   # "<brand>"
)           # End of Capturing Group (1)
(           # Capturing Group (2)
  [^<]      # Character not in [<] Character Class
  +         # (one or more)(greedy)
)           # End of Capturing Group (2)
(           # Capturing Group (3)
  <         # "<"
  \/        # "/"
  brand>    # "brand>"
)           # End of Capturing Group (3)
```

Comment: thank you for that. I tested it . But it is duplicating all the tags . I have multiple tags. I want just the brand tag to be duplicated

Comment: @user8128851, change pattern to `(<brand>)([^<]+)(<\/brand>)`, updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
(<brand>([^<]+)</brand>)
```

replace with:

```
\1\n<brand>\2 </brand>
```

Since you want to only want to work with the brand tag.  This copies the whole line, then will give you a new line with the stuff in 'brand' (everything up to the next non 'less than') and adds a space. Good luck!